# How to Update Group Price Programmatically Without Product Object Save

Tags: magento-1.9, group-price

To save group price for the products, the following works for me.

```
$product->setData('group_price', $group_pricing_data);
$product->save();
```

However, it takes a while for mass updating products. The faster way to save only attributes via saveAttribute() does not seem to work on group price.

```
$product->setData('group_price', $group_pricing_data);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'group_price');
```

Is it because group_price is not EAV like the other attributes, and if so, is there any other way to just save only group pricing?

Comment: did you get this to work @zhenming ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't simply update group price data using `saveAttribute` because it has a custom backend model, `catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice`.

When you load and save a product object, group price's custom resource mode does the work to load and save the data accordingly. If you look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Groupprice_Abstract`, you will see the methods Magento uses to load and save group price data.

Specifically, `savePriceData` shows how to save the data properly. If you want a fast group price update, you can mimic what's done here. Check how `$data` looks like, and you have a good place to start.

Comment: can you show an example with the above code? I can't get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up saving group_price attribute like this:

```
$prices = $product->getData('group_price');
```

above code return array, next step is to modify this array and last inject as parameter to below:

```
$product->setGroupPrice($prices)
            ->getResource()
            ->getAttribute('group_price')
            ->getBackend()
            ->afterSave($product);
```

5k products  45 ~ 60 sec on docker local environment.

Happy coding,
Adam

Comment: I cannot get this to work have you any ideas? "Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean "

Answer (score 0):

try to: var_dump($product->setGroupPrice($prices)
            ->getResource()
            ->getAttribute('group_price'));
and post here